# Best practice to use Python 2.7 decimal in predictable ways (for money)

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

Firstly, I'm a bit new to Python, I know this floating point arithmetic seems very basic but I can't find any duplicate/related question in SO

I have an acceptance test: expect `3.3 / 3` to be `1.1`

Then I tried..

```
from decimal import *
>>> Decimal(3.3) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('1.099999999999999940788105353')

>>> Decimal(3.3) / Decimal(3.0)
Decimal('1.099999999999999940788105353')

>>> Decimal('3.3') / Decimal('3')
Decimal('1.1') # as expected
```

Question: What is the best practice to use Python decimal in predictable ways? or that I just need to format every decimal display to string?

To be more specific: I'm writing a small automation script for loan data report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Shouldn't you use integers for money? Or maybe [**`fraction`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html, it is possible to set the precision for your operations. The default is 28 decimal points.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
Decimal(3.3) / Decimal(3)
```

This returns "Decimal('1.1')"

Comment: To get a predictable precision on input, use strings. To get predictable precision on output, use context's prec value.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that in the bare float `3.3` to Decimal you're already subject to floating-point imprecision:

```
>>> Decimal(3.3)
Decimal('3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
```

So, yes, you should always pass strings.